# Inequalities: Do these properties hold?

Tags: inequality

I was curious if the following inequalities hold.

**Inequality #1**

Assume $A, B, C, D$ are real numbers.

Given:

$A\le C$

$B\le D$

Does
$A+B\le C+D$ hold?

**Inequality #2**

Assume $A, B, C, D$ are real numbers, and $A, C\ge 0$.

Given:

$A\le C$

$B\le D$

Does $AB\le CD$ hold?

Comment: Inequality $\#2$ has issues, but if you insist that *all* of the terms are non-negative then it'll be made correct.  Take $A=1,C=10,B=-3,D=-2$ for a counterexample.  We successfully have $0\leq 1\leq 10$ and $-3\leq -2$ as desired so it matches your hypotheses, but $-3\times 1 > -2\times 10$.  Inequality $\#1$ is correct in all cases.

Comment: I have proven inequality #2 is incorrect (see below), inequality #2 would be correct if the sentence "Both B and D are negative" is not true.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\color{red}{A \leq C}$ and $\color{blue}{B \leq D}$ so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{red}{A}+B \leq \color{red}{C}+\color{blue}{B} \leq C +\color{blue}{D}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The other inequality follows similarly provided the values are positive.

Comment: What if B, D can be negative, but B <= D as stated in the assumption?

Comment: For inequality#1, all number can be negative

Comment: What about A * log(A) <= B * log(B) for 0 <= A <= B <= 1?

Comment: $0\leq A\leq B\leq 1$ entails that $\ln A\leq \ln B\leq 0$ so $$A\ln A\leq B\ln A\geq B\ln B$$So we can't say much about it.  Chains of comparisons are only transitive when they "point" in the same direction.

Answer (score 2):

For inequality #1)

Follow from given information, 
$A+B\le A+D\le C+D$, using [transitive property and addition property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)).

Simialaly,**If $A,B,C,D\ge 0$**, inequality#2 holds.

**However, only assuming $A,C\ge 0$, IT IS NOT TRUE. Consider the case $(A,B,C,D)=(0,-2,1,-1)$**

Answer (score 1):

The first inequality is absolutely correct.

The second inequality however:

If $0 \le B \le D$ then the inequality is correct.

If $B \le D \le 0$ then $-B, -D \ge 0$ and $-D\le-B$, combine with $0 \le A  \le C$, only the inequality $0 \le -AD \le -BC$ or $AD \ge BC$ is absolutely true, we can't infer anything from it to prove the comparison between $AB$ and $CD$.

If $B \le 0 \le D$, because $0 \le A \le C$, we will have $AB \le 0 \le CD$, the inequality is true.